# SP2007 - List all checked out / unversioned files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, migration, check-out, stsadm

I am in the process of migrating our SP2007 farm to SP2013 using a migration tool.

Where it is currently having issues, is where it skips documents that have "no checked in version".

I can see these documents if I go into each library, and then "Manage checked out files".

Is there a way through STADM or PowerShell that I can run a report across the farm to see all of these files?

I plan to e-mail the user and tell them to check it in, or lose it forever. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below ["Get All Checked Out Documents with no Checked In Version"](http://shipoint.com/2012/06/21/getting-a-list-of-all-checked-out-files-with-no-checked-in-versions-in-sharepoint-2007-using-powershell/)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)

function CheckedOutItems()
{
    $url=Read-Host “Please Enter In Site Url”
    “SiteURL ‘t” + “FileName ‘t” + “CheckedOutTo ‘t” + “ModifiedDate ‘t” + “Version” >> c:\temp\checkedoutfiles.csv
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
    $webs = $site.AllWebs

    foreach($web in $webs)
    {
        $listCollections=$web.Lists
        foreach($list in $listCollections)
        {
            if($list.BaseType.ToString() -eq “DocumentLibrary”)
            {
                $dList=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$list
                $items = $dList.Items
                $files = $dList.CheckedOutFiles
                foreach($file in $files
                {
                    $wuse=$file.DirName.Substring($web.ServerRelativeUrl.Length)
                    $web.Url + “‘t” + $wuse + “‘/” + $file.LeafName + “‘t” + $file.CheckedOutBy.Name + “‘t” + $file.TimeLastModified.ToString() + “‘t” + “No Checked In Version” >> c:\temp\checkedoutfiles.csv
                }
            }
        }
    $web.Dispose()
    }
$site.Dispose()
}

CheckedOutItems
```

Comment: Super, thanks. Just one notice - you need to update the line `foreach($file in $files` to be `foreach($file in $files)` as it's missing the last ) from the author.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link reusable codes are available just copy and paste the codes and change the web url.

http://www.topsharepoint.com/list-all-checked-out-items-using-powershell

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12966.sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-list-the-documents-checked-out-with-version-details-in-a-site-collection.aspx

http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/powershell-tech/powershell-tip-find-all-checked-out-files#.Vr2T_prVzcs